# How to prevent clicking through object in GameMaker

Tags: game-maker, events, objects

I've been making my first, simple game in Game Maker. You have to click a moving ball (obj_ball), each time you click it, it wil start moving faster. I wanted to add a way to lose the game: if you would miss a ball, it would redirect you to another room. I tried creating a new object (obj_gameover) covering the whole backgroud and adding a 'left pressed' event with a proper execute line to it, but whenever I click on a obj_ball, it also clicks on a obj_gameover, executing events from both objects. Is there any way to fix my problem?

Comment: holy misleading title batman, I'm gonna edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check in obj_gameover whether the ball is clicked too or not.
Something like:
**Left Pressed (obj_gameover):**

```
if (!obj_ball.clicked)
{
    // proceed your obj_gameover's onclick actions
}
```

Where **clicked** is the variable in obj_ball, which becomes true in obj_ball's Left Pressed, and becomes false in Step Event.

**HOWEVER**
I would like to suggest you to implement your system in a differeny way, without the giant obj_gameover. Use something like this in obj_ball's Step Event:
**Step Event (obj_ball):**

```
if (mouse_check_button_pressed(mb_left)) // if button is pressed...
    if (instance_position(mouse_x, mouse_y, obj_ball) == id) // if cursor is on object
    {
        // do all the actions you currently do in Left Pressed Event
    }
    else
    {
        // mouse is pressed, but cursor is not on the ball
        // do your gameover actions
    }
```

Comment: _Use something like this in obj_ball's Step Event:_ not `Step` but `Step End` for avoid lag.